# Memory Leak in CGContextDrawPDFPage in iOS 8.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, ios8

Under iOS 8.1 I'm getting a memory leak when rendering a PDF page into a graphics context with CGContextDrawPDFPage.  It doesn't happen in the simulator but I get hundreds of leaks of 272 bytes of malloc'd memory every time I do it (on iPad Air).  If I comment out the CGContextDrawPDFPage the leak goes away.

Does anyone else get similar behaviour?

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);


CGPDFPageRef page;

// Grab the PDF page
page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNo + 1);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, aRect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page); // <-  LEAKING?!?!?

// Would create the new UIImage from the context
//image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
```

Here's a stack trace (reversed):

malloc

38.58 MB      36.7% 148743        std::__1::list >::list(std::__1::list > const&)

19.61 MB      18.6% 75610          std::__1::vector CG::Path::Subpath CG::Allocator

19.61 MB      18.6% 75610           void std::__1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(CG::Path::Subpath&&)

19.61 MB      18.6% 75610            CG::Path::Sequence::move_to_point(CGPoint const&, CGAffineTransform const*)

19.61 MB      18.6% 75610             CGPathMoveToPoint

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506              TTrueTypeQuadOutlineContext::AddPoint(bool, int, int)

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506               TTrueTypeFontHandler::RenderGlyph(unsigned short, TTrueTypeQuadOutlineContext&, unsigned int) const

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                TTrueTypeFontHandler::GetOutlinePath(unsigned short, TGlyphOutlineBatch const&) const

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                 FPFontCopyGlyphPath

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                  CGFontCreateGlyphPath

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                   CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                    CGGlyphBuilder::create_missing_bitmaps(CGGlyphIdentifier const*, unsigned long, CGGlyphBitmap const**)

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                     render_glyphs

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                      draw_glyph_bitmaps

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                       ripc_DrawGlyphs

19.59 MB      18.6% 75506                        draw_glyphs

19.57 MB      18.6% 75434                         draw_glyphs

19.55 MB      18.6% 75359                          simple_draw

19.55 MB      18.6% 75359                           CGPDFTextLayoutDrawGlyphs

19.55 MB      18.6% 75348                            op_TJ

19.55 MB      18.6% 75348                             pdf_scanner_handle_xname

19.55 MB      18.6% 75348                              CGPDFScannerScan

19.55 MB      18.6% 75348                               CGPDFDrawingContextDrawPage

19.55 MB      18.6% 75348                                pdf_page_draw_in_context

19.55 MB      18.6% 75348                                 CGContextDrawPDFPage

Comment: You have the ios8 tag on this question and mention 8.1 in the title.  Can you please clarify?  Is the issue new to iOS 8.1 or did it occur in 8.0 as well?

Comment: Also, are you running this inside of an autorelease pool?  To be certain it's not a delayed deallocation, try adding `@autoreleasepool {}` around this code (note that obviously that would release the `image` that you eventually want to pass on but will at least eliminate that as a possibility).

Comment: I think it occurs in 8.0 too.  I've tried wrapping an autorelease block without success.  I've just got a stack trace of where the memory is leaking.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to match every call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`.

Per the [UIKit framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions):

> When you are done modifying the context, you must call the
>   `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` function to clean up the bitmap drawing
>   environment and remove the graphics context from the top of the
>   context stack. You should not use the `UIGraphicsPopContext` function to
>   remove this type of context from the stack.

Comment: It's there.  I've already called that to remove a leak.  It's still leaking!

Comment: Yes, I can see that it is there, with a comment that indicates that it fixes the leak.  I've added an explanation above as to why it is needed.  From your comment, it seems that I misunderstood your comment in code.  I'll edit your question to remove the misleading `// fix leak`

Comment: thanks.  sorry for not being clear.  the (existing leak) is really weird.  calling the function 100 times leaks a lot.  very noticeable in profiler!

Comment: @PaulPhoenix Did you find a solution?